# volley imageCache and imageRequest both cache the image

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, image-caching

i'm using volley to load my images and cache them.

```
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(getRequestQueue(context), mImageCache);
```

which mImageCache is a DiskLruImageCache.

volley fetches images from server by `ImageRequest` which extend the `ImageRequest<Bitmap>`

and in request class there is boolean that defines whether to cache the response or not

```
/** Whether or not responses to this request should be cached. */
private boolean mShouldCache = true;
```

and `ImageRequest` hasn't disabled `mShouldCache`.

as you can see the default value is true so after volley fetches an image caches it under the volley cache directory by `diskBasedCache`.

so now i have to cache bitmap one from `ImageRequest` and one from `ImageLoader` how can i disable `ImageRequest` cache ? or any other suggestions ?

Comment: I think you have to use AndroidQuery lib for load image from server url which provide various way to handle cached images from server :https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: thanks for library but i wanna stick with volley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a mistake giving the `ImageLoader` a disk cache. Volley already has a shared disk cache for every response, be it an image are not, that works according to HTTP cache headers by default.

You are supposed to provide a **memory** bitmap cache to the `ImageLaoder`. Look at the documentation.

The reasoning for it is how Volley is designed. This is the image request logic for Volley:

1. Image with url X is added to the queue.
2. Check image **memory** cache (provided by you) - If available, return bitmap. **quickest**
3. Check shared disk cache - If available, check cache headers to see that image is still valid. If valid - add to **memory** bitmap cache and return. **slower, but still pretty quick**
4. This step means that either the image was in the disk cache but its cache headers are missing or expired, or the image wasn't available in the cache at all. Either way, Volley performs a network request and caches the response in both caches. **slowest**

So by providing a disk cache - you are both slowing down your app and taking up to twice as much disk space with redundant image saving.

Use a **memory** cache.

Comment: but i need a DiskLruCache ! i sovled this problem by creating a new instance of requestQueue by myself and passed the NoCache as cache and used my own image cache !

Comment: You don't understand the code you are you using, and probably didn't understand my answer. If you want the disk cache, edit the Volley source and change the disk cache. The `ImageLoader` expects a memory cache. If you give it a disk cache, you are hurting your app, and the user by using redundant disk space.

Comment: but volleys diskBasedCache caches entities based on httpHeader and i want the images to be LRU cache ! is there any workaround ?

Comment: Edit the source. It's OK. That's why it's open.